# Is saving serial data in a data file via <fstream> in C++ common practice/practical?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, database

The question is pretty much in the title. I need to store 45 fields consisting of arrays of serial data. I'm planning to store these fields in a data file using fstream. I would like to have these fields available to a client PC that would be connected to my PC via a serial port(RS 232).

The general idea of my PC is to:

Aggregate data from a device -> save serial data using fstream -> finally, listen for requests from the client upon which the server PC will then send the serial data to its parent.

I'm just curious if this method of data saving is practical or if I should be saving serial data another way. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Can't answer this question in a general sense because it depends on too many unspecified requirements. Depends on the data, the usage pattern, level of data integrity required...

Comment: @user4581301 I made an edit with more detail. Hopefully it's more clear.